# JavaScript Apostrophe escape with code behind call (C#/VB)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am struggling with **apostrophe** in JavaScript call. Problem is, that casual solutions like replacing **apostrophe** with

```
\', &#39; \u0027
```

are not working because I am creating JavaScript action dynamically.

Example:

HTML Part:

```
<img onmouseover="ShowNote('<%= instance("note") %>')">
```

Code behind part:

```
instance("note") = "John's room is awful";
```

The thing is, that once aspx.net reaches **<%= instance("note") =>'** part it replaces it with it's representation leading to creating this in source code:

```
<img onmouseover="ShowNote('John's room is awful')">
```

And this is not working as expected.

Is there any way to resolve this? As mentioned above. None of the replacement is working.

Comment: Aside from the syntax error in the closing server tag on your "HTML Part", what exactly is the problem?  It's not clear what the issue is here.

Comment: @David Thanks for info. Fixed.. Well the problem is, that aspx replaces instance("note") in html part with **John's Room is awful** and then it looks like: <img onmouseover="ShowNote('John's Room is awful')> and because there are 3 apostrophes it wont work

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should not use inline event handlers. If your server side code builds output like `<img onmouseover="ShowNote('John's room is awful')">` then it can safely be assessed that you have a ton of XSS vulnerabilities and *must* refactor your code.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the apostrophe in the string with the hotel entity for it?

Comment: @box86rowh what exactly do you mean by hotel entity?

Comment: Html. .. stupid auto correct

Comment: @box86rowh yes, as mentioned above. &#39; is not working in this case and &apos; is not valid html entity (http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/07/01/the_curse_of_apos/)

Comment: what does it do when you use the &#39; ?

Comment: @box86rowh it is replaced with apostrophe (') and it leads to the same